# How to import a package installed using pip in python

Tags: numpy, import, module, pip, package

I have installed numpy using pip, but when I do "import numpy" in python it cannot find the module. The website says that this ought to work so I am unsure where I have gone wrong. This was the website I followed.
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-numpy
The only way that I can make it work is via import sys and specifying exactly the file path each time which is a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue that's arising out of having multiple versions of python installed on your computer and/or pip installing it to a specific directory.

If it is because of multiple versions being installed

```
py -"version_number" -m pip install "module_name"
```

will probably work

Comment: How would I stop pip installing it to a specific directory?

Comment: @Ahmed, first of all, do you have multiple versions of python installed?

Comment: I do not think so. I went onto programs and there was only one version of python there (3.9)

Comment: @Ahmed can you check what happens when you execute what I've written in my updated answer? (I am assuming that you are using windows)